# How do you make grouped objects a focus point without moving the camera?

Tags: depth-of-field

In my blend, I am trying to focus on a pile of doughnuts and then focus on them. While doing this, blurring the background and the side windows without losing some of the detail on them but making them quite blurred. How would I do this? I Have tried making an object a focus but it is not achieving my desired finish. This is a sort of blur I am looking for...

[image]

I will atatch my .blend file if you would like to see.

[image]

Comment: This is generally done in post production in the Compositor with nodes. Can also be done directly in the 3D view but it is computationally more expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an empty and place it where you want to focus.

[image]

Set the empty as the focus object and lower the value of he F-stop to reduce the depth of field.

[image]

[image]

You might need to increase the number of samples to deal with noise.

---

Comment: How can I see more of the doughnuts they seem not enough focused? If you can, can you share the blend file?

Comment: Play with the values for the f-stop.

Comment: One last question about this project which I am finding complicated is, how do I make it so that the rain drops from the particle system is on both of the sides but there are less inside than outside and so I can see them as well on the outside, because it looks a bit unrealistic with that much rain/condensation on the inside. Or if I need not because it looks fine then do tell me.

Comment: This is not a forum, new questions should be asked as different posts. Use the big blue "Ask Question" link on the top right of the page.